# How to remove unused Menu Bar items

Tags: macos, ui

I have some Menu Bar items which I don't use (the bar on top of screen), any advice how to remove them? I've disabled SIP so I can edit system-level stuff.

For instance, I have Razer Synapse menu item, it's there even though I uninstalled Razer Synapse software, any tips how to get rid of the icon?

[image]

I'm on MacOS 11.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get rid of it by looking in Launch Daemons and Launch Agents folders and deleting everything with "Razer" in it

Answer (score 0):

Anything with a menu bar item can't be uninstalled by simply deleting the relevant app.

You'll need to go through each item individually, see if there's a remaining uninstaller in your Applications/Utilities folder, or if not Google "app name complete uninstall macos"

Note, this search will throw up many results from companies trying to sell you their uninstaller software. If you're lucky they will actually include a real manual uninstall method as well. Your best result will often be from the software manufacturer, who may make a separately-downloadable uninstaller.

Answer (score 0):

You need to completely uninstall the apps causing trouble. Just deleting an app from `/Applications` does not remove all traces an app. The traces are usually in `~/Library` or `/Library`, but can be elsewhere.

Instructions for Razer Synapse uninstall are here [wikiHow](https://www.wikihow.com/Uninstall-Razer-Synapse-on-PC-or-Mac).

You will need to do your own searches to find uninstall instructions for your other apps.

Alternatively get a quality app uninstaller (which will likely not be free). I recommend:

- [Remove-It](http://www.osxbytes.com), or
- [App Cleaner & Uninstaller Pro](https://nektony.com/mac-app-cleaner).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, SIP should be irrelevant -- you don't need it off to *install* those menulets in the first place).

'Normal' menulets can be removed by holding Command and dragging the menulet off the menubar. However, third-party apps can use other methods that don't respond to this.

You need to follow the instructions for uninstalling from the companies' websites.

I would not recommend using any 'cleaner' apps, as they can cause more harm than good.